# How to check every single rows of Django database table for True or False values in a field and perform calculation based on it?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table in my Django app which has the following model class :-

```
  class LiveRoutes(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       route = models.ForeignKey(UserRoutes)
       status = models.ForeignKey(LiveRoutesStatus)
       traveller = models.ManyToManyField('LiveRouteTravellers')
       datetime = models.DateTimeField()
       calculated = models.NullBooleanField()
       def __unicode__(self):
         return self.route.__unicode__()
```

I want to define a function to perform calculations on the data of each row and after performing the calculation, I want to set the calculate value to False, so that I dont calculate it again. I am not sure how to achieve this? OR Whether it is possible to achieve?

```
       def CheckTheCalculateField(self):
         #code to check the value in calculate field of each row
```

Any help would be highly appreciated and thankfully received.

Comment: what is your formula? Or how would you like to calculate it?

Comment: @catherine Thanks, I am using haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points in the routes. For that I am drawing data from different table, this table only has the routes of the journey. So if the value is Null or Flase I can draw data and calculate but to enter the calculation I need an if condition. How to find the value of calculated to do the if. Hope I am able to convey it you?

Comment: Thanks @catherine. Thanks to you too, Its good to be receiving help from you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for route in LiveRoutes.objects.filter(calculated=False).iterator():
    # Do your calculation

    route.calculated = True
    route.save()
```

You have a complication in that you have calculated as a `NullBooleanField`. You probably want it as a normal boolean field with a default of `False`.

You also have a number of potential problems with database transactions depending on how this gets called and what other activity is happening at the same time.

An alternative is django-async. With that you would post a job to do the calculation which would happen some time later. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-async/

Comment: Thanks. So the calculated should be models.BooleanField(default = False).

And what are the complications that you have mentioned? Please elaborate.

Comment: One example is that you might have a race between doing a calculation and marking it as complete, and the data that you are calculating over changing. If this is called from within a Django view then you might also end up calculating several times for the same LiveRoutes instance. Depending on how you record the calculation results this may be no worse than wasted effort, but could also corrupt the results in the worst case.

Comment: Oh! now I understood. I'll take care of it.